# How to send query to a php page and get html data in php?

Tags: php, html, email, load

I am trying to send a html email from a php class in which the data is determined by the data sent to the class's method.

for example.

```
public function send_warning_email($user_id, $email){
   global $mail;
   $body = file_get_contents('email_processor.php');
   /// ohter codes  
}
```

In above example. I want to send query to the email_processor.php page and get the return plain text and assign it to the $body variable.

Is there another function I can use instead of file_get_contents() that will allow me to send query to the php page and get return text or another approach to performing this task?.

Comment: What do you mean "send query to the page"? You can have a form in which the user inserts his text and make email_processor.php page get this form (`<form action="email_processor.php ...>`.

Comment: is `email_processor.php` on your own site?

Comment: the email_proccessor.php is in my site

Answer (score 3):

You can require your email_processor.php:

```
$body = require 'email_processor.php';
```

In this case you must `return` some body in your `email_processor.php`

Another case: you can use output buffer:

```
ob_start();
require 'email_processor.php';
$body = ob_get_clean();
```

In this case you must echo some body in your `email_processor.php`

Answer (score 1):

Use `CURL`

```
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'email_processor.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);     
// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: this does not work, thanks for your attempt. is there another way?

Comment: @slb what is not work? I am using same code for my work and it is working perfectly.

Comment: @slb did you change the `$data` in `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data); ` to the correct data you wanted to post?

Comment: please can you show me how to format the data. lets say i want to send $data='id=66&new=po'. and the email_processor.php is has something like     if(isset($_POST['id'])){ $id=$_POST['id']; // continue to process }

Answer (score 0):

some OS will only read it when you pass it like this:

`$body = file_get_contents('./email_processor.php');`